# How to reuse tests in Yii2 Codeception

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, code-reuse, codeception

I am setting up new project based on Yii2 and Codeception. I am using advanced app template (backend, common, frontend).

I want most of frontend ActiveRecords to be "ReadOnly" so I made special Trait where I am blocking appropriate methods like save, insert, delete, update, ...

```
trait ReadOnlyActiveRecord {

/**
 * @throws \yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
public function save($runValidation = true, $attributeNames = null)
{
    return self::throwNotAllowedException(__FUNCTION__);
}

//...
```

It simply throws an MethodNotAllowedHttpException.

Now I use this Trait in multiple frontend ARs and want to test them using Codeception like following

```
use \Codeception\Specify;

/**
 * @expectedException \yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
public function testSaveMethod()
{
    $model = new AppLanguage();

    $this->specify('model should be unsaveable', function () use ($model) {

        expect('save function is not allowed', $model->save())->false();
    });
}

/**
 * @expectedException \yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 */
public function testInsertMethod()
{
    $model = new AppLanguage();

    $this->specify('model should be unisertable', function () use ($model) {

        expect('insert function is not allowed', $model->save())->false();
    });
}

// ...
```

I now I am figuring out how to use these tests in multiple TestCests so I won't rewrite the code again and again in each of Cest.

So I am thinking about something like

```
/**
 * Tests ActiveRecord is read only
 */
public function testReadOnly()
{
    $model = new AppLanguage();

    $this->processReadOnlyTests($model);
}
```

So my question is:

**Where to put the test methods and how to include and call them in specific Cests?**

Any suggestions?

Thank you.